# UPDATE with NULL char in the middle of std::string or char array

Tags: c++, occi

We are using Oracle 12c database and CentOS7 with OCCI to connect. We are trying to insert a char array into the database, but this char array has a NUL character in the middle. When we use the statement->setString function the update is successful however once it sees the NUL char it only puts NUL chars there after. See this example code and it's output.

**Example Code using setString:**

```
static void Run(const std::string &connectionString, const std::string &user, const std::string &pwd)
{
    Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment();

    Connection *conn = env->createConnection(user, pwd, connectionString);

    Statement *stmt = conn->createStatement("UPDATE my_customers SET first_name = :1 WHERE customer_id = :2");

    stmt->setString(1, std::string("GEO\0RGE              ", 20));
    stmt->setInt(2, 10);

    stmt->setString(1, std::string(adrs_first_name, sizeof(adrs_first_name)));

    oracle::occi::Statement::Status status = stmt->execute();

    conn->terminateStatement(stmt);
    conn->commit();
}
```

**Accessing the Database After the Update:**

```
SELECT first_name FROM my_customers WHERE customer_id = 10;

GEO

SELECT rawtohex(first_name) FROM my_customers WHERE customer_id = 10;

47454F0000000000000000000000000000000000
```

However I would have expected it to be

```
47454F0047452032322020202020202020202020
```

So I tried using oracle::occi::Bytes-- this errors out with

*ORA - 12899: value too large for column "MAIN_USER"."MY_CUSTOMERS"."FIRST_NAME" (actual : 40, maximum : 20)*

**Example Code using setBytes:**

```
static void Run(const std::string &connectionString, const std::string &user, const std::string &pwd)
{
    Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment();
    Connection *conn = env->createConnection(user, pwd, connectionString);
    Statement *stmt = conn->createStatement("UPDATE my_customers SET first_name = :1 WHERE customer_id = :2");
    std::string s("GEO\0RGE              ", 20);
    oracle::occi::Bytes bytes((unsigned char *)s.c_str(), 20, 0, env);
    stmt->setBytes(1, bytes);
    stmt->setInt(2, 10);
    try
    {

        oracle::occi::Statement::Status status = stmt->execute();
    }
    catch (oracle::occi::SQLException &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Error " << e.getErrorCode() << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    conn->terminateStatement(stmt);
    conn->commit();
}
```

**Output:**

```
Error 12899 : ORA - 12899 : value too large for column "MAIN_USER"."MY_CUSTOMERS"."FIRST_NAME" (actual : 40, maximum : 20)
```

So I tried sending in half the bytes by changing the 2nd parameter of the oracle::occi::Bytes constructor to 10, and it succeeded however after reading the value from the database I realized it is a string representation of the hex value of the chars. So my question at this point is why is Oracle12c putting the hex value as a string when I pass oracle::occi:Bytes.

**Example Code using half the actual length and setBytes:**

```
static void Run(const std::string &connectionString, const std::string &user, const std::string &pwd)
{
    Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment();
    Connection *conn = env->createConnection(user, pwd, connectionString);
    Statement *stmt = conn->createStatement("UPDATE my_customers SET first_name = :1 WHERE customer_id = :2");

    std::string s("GEO\0RGE              ", 20);
    oracle::occi::Bytes bytes((unsigned char *)s.c_str(), 10, 0, env);

    stmt->setBytes(1, bytes);
    stmt->setInt(2, 10);
    try
    {
        oracle::occi::Statement::Status status = stmt->execute();
    }
    catch (oracle::occi::SQLException &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Error " << e.getErrorCode() << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    conn->terminateStatement(stmt);
    conn->commit();
}
```

Accessing the Database After the Update :
    SELECT first_name FROM my_customers WHERE customer_id = 10;

```
47454F00524745202020
```

*NOTE : This query did not wrap with rawtohex-- this is the actual char array value in the database.*

**Here is the table definition:**

```
DESCRIBE MAIN_USER.MY_CUSTOMERS

Name                           Null Type
------------------------------ ---- --------------
CUSTOMER_ID                         NUMBER(10)
FIRST_NAME                          CHAR(20 CHAR)
```

Here is our Oracle instance information :
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

We are using Oracle occi client 12.1 64bit

Comment: *but this char array has a NUL character in the middle* -- Meaning this is  data with ASCII non-printable control characters in it, thus all bets are off when the system encounters one of these characters.  Why not Base64 encode the string, and write that as the character data?  Or save it as binary data, similar to how you would save image data to the database?

Comment: std::string supports all characters, more or less it is just a list of characters. We would expect that when sending a std::string with a length to setString it would put all characters specified by the length of std::string , not just up to a control character

Comment: I know that `std::string` supports NULL characters.  The problem is that you're making an assumption as to how `setString` operates when given a string with a null character, and the length goes beyond the null character.  Unless the docs for this function explicitly states what it does, or you have the source code to this function, you can't assume how it handles the string.  Even if setString did do what you say, how does the database handle control characters within `CHAR` types?  To alleviate this, you could store a Base64 encoded string.  That's what Base64 is built for.

Comment: I agree with that statement -- however if you read my question, you would notice I did try to use setBytes because of your exact statement. This in turn caused a different issue. I would like to point out the issue is not whether or not std::string can contain NULL, the issue/question I am asking is "HOW DO I GET A NULL CHAR INTO THE DATABASE USING AN UPDATE STATETMENT THROUGH OCCI?"

Comment: Do you have another utility program (SQLDeveloper maybe?) that can set that CHAR(20) column to a string that has embedded control characters?  You don't want to waste your time trying to do something programatically with OCCI if the results you're looking for can't really be achieved.  Maybe this is really an Oracle DB `CHAR` issue, and not one of occi or selectString.

Comment: Yes we have other processes inserting this data, but not through OCCI - so we know it is achievable. We can read the data out of the database we just can't insert/update it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that may stumble upon this, I ended up talking with Oracle Support and they told me there wasn't a way to do what I wanted (as expected) however the Byte workaround got us closer and we were able to take the hex string being passed in by the setBytes and turn it into raw data and then convert that raw data to a varchar2 which ended up "working" -- however I don't know what implications we will run into later, but so far it seems to work.

**Code:**

```
static void Run(const std::string &connectionString, const std::string &user, const std::string &pwd)
{
    Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment();
    Connection *conn = env->createConnection(user, pwd, connectionString);
    Statement *stmt = conn->createStatement("UPDATE my_customers SET first_name = utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(hextoraw(:1)) WHERE customer_id = :2");

    std::string s("GEO\0RGE              ", 20);
    oracle::occi::Bytes bytes((unsigned char *)s.c_str(), 20, 0, env);

    stmt->setBytes(1, bytes);
    stmt->setInt(2, 10);
    try
    {
        oracle::occi::Statement::Status status = stmt->execute();
    }
    catch (oracle::occi::SQLException &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Error " << e.getErrorCode() << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    conn->terminateStatement(stmt);
    conn->commit();
}
```

**Then checking the database:**

```
SELECT rawtohex(first_name) FROM my_customers WHERE customer_id = 10;

47454F0052474520202020202020202020202020
```

So it seems to work